# Unable to debug sum of a list using recursion in Python

Tags: python, recursion

```
def sumList(arr):
    items = len(arr)
    if(items == 0):
        return 0
    elif(items == 1):
        return arr[0]
    else:
        return(arr[0] + sumList(arr[1:]))

print(sumList([2, 4, 6, 10, 123]))
```

This code will still run if the "else if" part is commented out. But, shouldn't the last `else` give an error for the last case when only one item is present as it's returning the list starting from index 1, which does not exist?

Comment: Do you mean that the code still run when when the elif part is commented ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's clarify the question: you seem to be asking why this code:

```
def sumList(array):
    items = len(array)

    if items == 0:
        return 0

    if items == 1:
        return array[0]

    return array[0] + sumList(array[1:])
```

still works if/when we remove the *second* conditional expression:

```
def sumList(array):
    items = len(array)

    if items == 0:
        return 0

    #if items == 1:
    #   return array[0]

    return array[0] + sumList(array[1:])
```

And the answer that @Tomothy32 provides tells us that the last line will eventually become:

```
return array[0] + sumList([])
```

Which due to your *first* conditional expression, becomes:

```
return array[0] + 0
```

In Python 3 we can express this as simply:

```
def sumList(array):
    if not array:  # empty containers are false in boolean context
        return 0

    head, *tail = array  # Python 2: head, tail = array[0], array[1:]

    return head + sumList(tail)
```

Answer (score 3):

Slices will never give an index out-of-range error. For example:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3]
print(mylist[10000:])
# []
```